# Headers in row 3?

Tags: r

I have a csv where the headers are in row 3 and way above something like second headers.

I included

```
 header = TRUE
```

and it simply got one row above. Now it is in row 2 so not alright yet.

```
a=read.csv('dataset.csv',header=TRUE)
```

here is how it looks after the `header=TRUE`:

```
             X.21     X.22
1                         
2 Default_On_Payment Count
3                  0     1
4                  0     1
5                  0     1
6                  0     1
```

How to remove the x.21 and make the appropriate column name be in the position of x.21 etc.?

Comment: Please check your csv file if there are blank rows.  If that is the case use `skip=2` in the `read.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `read.csv` with `skip` argument

```
read.csv('dataset.csv',header=TRUE, skip = 2)
```